# How to set up a VPC for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I want to set up a **VPC for my Elastic Beanstalk web app** and **RDS postgres db**. I tried creating a VPC but ran into problems:

I went to `VPC on AWS` -> `Launch VPC Wizard` -> `VPC with Public and Private Subnets`. I am not sure what configurations to use. For example, what should I set `Elastic IP Allocation ID`? Do I need to set the VPC name?

**After I create this, am I ready to just add it in EBS and RDS, or is there something else I need to do?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to set the VPC name?

Its optional, but you can use, e.g. `MyVPCforEB` or what you want. It easier to find your vpc by name, than by cryptic vpc-id.

> what should I set Elastic IP Allocation ID

You have to create EIP first. Its done in `VPC -> Elastic IP addresses` menu. This is required for NAT gateway, so that instances in private subnet can access the internet.

> After I create this, am I ready to just add it in EBS and RDS, or is there something else I need to do?

**Not really.** To do it properly, you would need to **add one more private subnet**. The VPC wizard will create only one private subnet. For RDS, to create a subnet group, you need to have at least **two private subnets** in different Availability Zones.

Thus, once you have two private subnets in two different AZs, then you can create new `Subnet Group` in RDS with the subnets. Having this, you can create the RDS in these two subnets.

Comment: Hi Marcin! So when I create an ```EIP```, should I select ```Amazon Pool``` or ```Owned by Me```? Really really appreciate your help!!

Comment: @NGI Amazon Pool. It will give you one IP address from Amazon range.

Comment: Thanks! I created the VPC. To add a subnet, I went to ```VPC``` -> ```Subnets```. I can name it anything right? As for VPC, I select the one just created and a different availability zone from my other private subnet. What do I set for ```IPv4 CIDR block```? Thanks again!! : ) Learning a lot

Comment: @NGI. Yes. You can try `10.0.10.0/24` assuming it does not clash with other subnets. You will also have to modify its route table to point to the NAT gateway. Check how it is done in the other private subnet, and do similar.

Comment: I believe I created the private subnet correctly. I went to ```Route Tables``. By "modify its route table" do you mean create a new one? In what way should I modify it? I understand that this is probably tedious.. really appreciate your help though ;)

Comment: @NGI Its getting confusing. I don't know the current state of your VPC. Its difficult to imagine all the route tables and other settings based on the comments. I think new question would be better where you could provide all the details of how is your VPC setup and what is the new issue. Can you screenshots if this saves time. Sorry, can't help better.

Comment: No worries Marcin, Ill make a new question and make this one an answer as I think it provides a good outline.

Comment: I added the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963105/how-can-i-create-a-vpc-for-ebs-and-rds Thank you SOO much for your help!