# How can I create a VPC for EBS and RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I made a Django app and deployed it on `Elastic Beanstalk`. I made a Postgres DB with `RDS` as well. I want to add both of these to a `VPC`.

I created the `VPC` using the **VPC wizard** (VPC with Public and Private Subnets): which created, as the name suggests, **one public and one private VPC**.

I was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941135/how-to-set-up-a-vpc-for-elastic-beanstalk) that I need to add a second private subnet for RDS. Now I have:

```
1 public subnet (10.0.0.0/24)
2 private subnets (10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.10.0/24)
```

I also know that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941135/how-to-set-up-a-vpc-for-elastic-beanstalk) that I needed to "modify the route table of the new private subnet to point to the NAT gateway". However, I am not sure what that means. Right now, here is what my route tables look like:

```
One for the public subnet
One for the private subnet (main)
```

Also, after configuring this, what do I need to do to add my RDS to this? Should I just make a subnet group with these 2 private subnets and set it when configuring the RDS? I think I know how to do EBS using CLI.

Please let me know if you need any more information! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **private subnets** your route tables should point 0.0.0.0/0 to NAT gateway, as shown on the screenshot:

[image]

Example SG for RDS for testing:

[image]

Comment: Hey Marcin! Long time no see! Thank you so much for your continued help. Will give this a shot right now!

Comment: Huh, looks like it was automatically configured like that. I will continue with the process and add some comments here. Thank you again!

Comment: @NGI No problem. I also added screenshot for subnet groups when you create RDS. In the group you need to specify the two private subnets of yours.

Comment: I successfully made the subnet group and created an RDS postgres db with it!! Thanks so much for your help thus far! is the next step to just make an EBS app and add it to the VPC, then connect the rds db to it?

Comment: @NGI Glad to hear. Probably will need to adjust security groups:-) Specifically, your RDS's security group must allow inbound access from the security group of your EB instance(s).

Comment: I see! Looks like I got ahead of myself haha! So, I see this security group rule `EC2 Security Group - Inbound`. Does it have to do with this? How should I allow inbound access?

Comment: @NGI As a quick fix for testing you can add inbound rule the the SG of the RDS allow traffic from the CIDR of the VPC (10.0.0.0/16). This way, any instance in the subnet, including EB instances, will be able to connect to the rds. I added example screenshot of the rule.

Comment: Done. This is making a lot more sense for me now that the pieces are coming together. Now RDS should be all hooked up, right? The next step is to just create a new RDS instance and then connect the RDS instance right? Again, thank you SO much!!

Comment: @NGI Theoretically yes, but in practice something will not work, was misconfigured or missed. Its normal. But you are close :-) Finger crossed :-)

Comment: Right! Definitely getting close though!!! There is one last thing, making a new post about it though as it is somewhat a separate topic. I can't say how much this helps!!

Comment: @NGI No problem. :-)

Comment: I've added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963690/how-to-configure-vpc-for-elastic-beanstalk-using-cli. Appreciate your help, again!