# How to configure VPC for Elastic Beanstalk using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am able to create an `Elastic Beanstalk` environment with a `VPC` using this command with `eb-cli`:

```
eb create --vpc
```

This asks me to configure several options:

```
Enter an RDS DB username (default is "ebroot"): ...
Enter an RDS DB master password: ...
Retype password to confirm: ...
Enter the VPC ID: ...
Do you want to associate a public IP address? (Y/n): ...
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon EC2 subnets: ...
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon ELB subnets: ...
Do you want the load balancer to be public? (Select no for internal) (Y/n): ...
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon VPC security groups: ...
Creating application version archive ...
```

I have created a VPC with subnets and added an RDS instance to it following this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941135/how-to-set-up-a-vpc-for-elastic-beanstalk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963105/how-can-i-create-a-vpc-for-ebs-and-rds) (thank you @Marcin!). But, there are a few things that I am confused about:

1. What is *"Do you want to associate a public IP address?"*
2. I remember creating subnets for my VPC, but what does it want me to add for the *"EC2 subnets"* and the *"ELB subnets"*? Should I add the ones from my VPC?
3. For *"Do you want the load balancer to be public?"*, what does this exactly mean? I am assuming that public means that it is public on the internet, whereas private means I can only access it in the VPC?
4. For *"Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon VPC security groups"*, do I need to add anything here?

I know these are pretty open ended, but hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: I would suggest setting the EB environment in console first to  to get to know the process of setting up VPC in EB and doing some initial testing of connectivity to RDS. Then you can attempt to recreate the setup in eb cli.

Comment: @Marcin yeah, good idea. So I started setting up a sample application and went to the VPC tab. It asks some similar questions, for example: what should I assign a public IP address? Also, asks for instance subnets: do I just set the two private ones here?

Comment: Is it single-instance env or load-balanced one?

Comment: @Marcin I only have one instance, so I think single-instance, but is there a way to check? Sorry for my lack of knowledge on this stuff. Learning a lot from you though :0!

Comment: If single-instance then you have to place your instance in public subnet and need a public IP. In the first page of configuration page it says at the top what environment is that, single instance, highly available (i.e. load balanced) etc.

Comment: @Marcin I see, looks like mine is load balanced. What should be done in that case? Thanks!!

Comment: So Load Balancer should be in public subnet, instances in private intances as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/lzzyTwe.png)

Comment: Guess it will fail. For application load balancer need two public subnets in two different AZs :-)

Comment: Got it, makes sense!! Though this process makes sense to me, I am still confused as to what it is referring to with `Amazon EC2 subnets` and `Amazon ELB subnets`. Also, do any `Amazon VPC security groups` need to be added? Thank you so much. I can finally see the light at the end of the tunnel ;)

Comment: @Marcin I see, should I make another public subnet in the VPC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218060/discussion-between-marcin-and-ngi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the chat discussion and comments.

1. What is "Do you want to associate a public IP address?"

For single instance EB env, it the EB should be in a public subnet with public IP.

2. I remember creating subnets for my VPC, but what does it want me to add for the "EC2 subnets" and the "ELB subnets"? Should I add the ones from my VPC?

For Load-balanced EB env, your load balancer should be in public subnets, while instances can be in private.

3. For "Do you want the load balancer to be public?", what does this exactly mean? I am assuming that public means that it is public on the internet, whereas private means I can only access it in the VPC?

Load balancer must be in public subnets. Without that, you won't be able to connect to your website from the internet.

4. For "Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon VPC security groups", do I need to add anything here?

You can use default ones, but may need to adjust them later if needed.

Comment: Hi Marcin, there is one problem that arised, I linked it in our chat here, if others need to see: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218060/discussion-between-marcin-and-ngi